# Answer a collection of emails in a batch using Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I've received a big load of emails. I want to answer them all with the same message without the recipients knowing of the other receivers. Any recommendations on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way I can think of is an outlook vba macro, provided you don't mind Outlook throwing a bit of a tantrum that you're automating it - it'll warn you that it might be a virus.

Something like the following

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim outlookFolder As Object, innerFolder As MAPIFolder
    Set outlookFolder = ns.Folders("Mailbox - Your mailbox name")
    Debug.Print outlookFolder.Name
    Set innerFolder = outlookFolder.Folders("Inbox")
    Debug.Print vbTab & innerFolder.Name
    Dim emailItem As MailItem
    For Each emailItem In innerFolder.Items
        If emailItem.Subject = "Test" Then
            Dim replyEmail As MailItem
            Set replyEmail = emailItem.Reply
            replyEmail.Body = "Test 2"
            replyEmail.Display
            replyEmail.Send
        End If

    Next it
End Sub
```

So for the above, for each email it finds in your inbox with the subject "Test", it'll send a reply to the original sender with the body "Test 2".

Answer (score 5):

Use **bcc** (blind carbon copy). Add all the recipients to that field and they won't know about all the other people you've also sent the mail to.

Comment: @alex exactly what i was gonna say

Comment: That forces me to put them in my address book which I want to avoid if possible.

Comment: No, just copy/paste their addresses from the incoming emails into the BCC field...

Comment: Yes, but the amount of emails I want to answer makes manual copy/paste for every address a tremendous and tiresome task.

Comment: I don't think you can do it any other way in Outlook. In Lotus Notes, for instance, you can choose a bunch of emails from different people and press **Reply to all**; that way, the To field is automatically filled from all the selected emails. In Outlook such a thing is not possible.